# Strange inequality in the proof of differentiability of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-series

I am looking at a proof and I found a strange inequality.

Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}^d$ then it is stated that $\sum_{j=1}^d{(2\pi)^{2k}n_j^{2k}}>>\parallel n\parallel_2^{2k}$ due to the inequality $\parallel n\parallel_2\leq\sqrt{d}\max_{j=1,...,d}{\mid n_j\mid}$. I really don't see it.

Comment: There is a typo in the inequality, it should read $$\|n\|_2 \leq \sqrt{d} \max_j |n_j|,$$ I suppose.

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{j=1}^d |n_j|^{2k} \geq \max_{j=1,\ldots,d} |n_j|^{2k}$$ implies, using the mentioned inequality,

$$(2\pi)^{2k} \sum_{j=1}^d n_j^{2k} \geq (2\pi)^{2k} \max_{j=1,\ldots,d} |n_j|^{2k} \geq \left( \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{d}} \right)^{2k} \|n\|_2^{2k}$$

Comment: Thanks :) I guess I was confused by $>>$..